# Ansible skipping playbook at first attempt on multiple-play playbook file

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have the following playbook:

```yaml
- import_playbook: "infrastructure/infrastructure.yml"
- import_playbook: "application/application.yml"
```

Inside these playbooks there are other playbooks being invoked, what happens is that in a specific moment one playbook will be executed in the `application.yml` pointed to `cicd_servers` group, and it will be skipped unintentionally.

See my inventory below:

```
[cicd_servers] 
sig-cicd-01 ansible_connection=local
```

This playbook in specific is that one below:

```yaml
---
- hosts: cicd_servers   
    gather_facts: false   
    remote_user: ansible   
    connection: local

  roles:
    - application/os_setup
    - application/jdk_install
    - infrastructure/jenkins_install
    - infrastructure/maven_install
    - infrastructure/scm_install
    - infrastructure/soapui_install
    - database/sqlplus-install

################### cicd server applications ############
- hosts: cicd_servers   
    become: true   
    remote_user: ansible   
    connection: local   
  
    roles:
    - application/fmw_cicd_conf
    - application/fmw_performance_conf
```

I don't know why it's skipping only this host, I tried also to remove the parameters `ansible_connection=local` from the inventory and `connection: local` from the playbook to the DNS Name of the machine, and it doesn't work as well.

**Note**: If I just play again the same playbook it won't skip these tasks, that is, it only does not work at first attempt.

**Note2**: If I comment a few playbooks before it, it executes successfully at first attempt, but I need to get it as it should be.

**Note3**: I'm using ansible 2.9.10 version.

Below I registered 2 outputs with verbose (`-vvvv`) to try to identify something, but the output in the part being skipped doesn't say nothing.

```
output_1 (success)
PLAY [cicd_servers] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
META: ran handlers
Thursday 21 January 2021  13:34:33 +0000 (0:00:21.729)       0:01:55.599 ******
included: /home/ansible/workspace_VFPT/roles/application/os_setup/tasks/infra.yml for sig-cicd-01.mgm.mw.sat.stp.vodafone.pt
Thursday 21 January 2021  13:34:33 +0000 (0:00:00.063)       0:01:55.663 ******
<sig-cicd-01.mgm.mw.sat.stp.vodafone.pt> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ansible
```

```
output_2 (failed)

PLAY [cicd_servers] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

PLAY [cicd_servers] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
```

If you guys have any idea what is causing it, please let me know.

Comment: Hi Daniel, welcome to SO. Please use the provided code formatting markup to post the error messages you are experiencing, since your question will not be useful to future folks when that Google Drive folder is deleted. That said, the "broken pipe" message implies the target machine abruptly broke your ssh connection, and thus this question belongs on https://ServerFault.com instead

Comment: Thanks. If anyone needs to see the link on ServerFault.com, here it is: https://serverfault.com/questions/1050715/ansible-skipping-playbook-at-first-attempt-on-multiple-play-playbook-file